# Check the value of an element and take action

Tags: javascript, html, verification

I would like a function that checks if some fields of the form have been filled out and if true it would execute a code of mine, if false it would do nothing.

In short, I would like to know how I check the fields, the code that will be executed, I already have it ready.

**HTML of the fields I want to check if they have been filled out:**

```
<!-- verifica select -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-md-4">
  <label for="InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.1</strong> Circunscrição policial
  </label>
  <select asp-for="InqueritoModel.COD_INQUERITO_CIRCUNSCRICAO_POLICIAL "
          asp-items="Model.ListCircunscricao"
          id="InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial"
          class="select-codigo"
          onchange="mostrarOutroDeCombo(this, 'DSC_OUTRO_INQUERITO_CIRCUNSCRICAO_POLICIAL')">
    <option value="">Selecione a circunscrição</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- verifica input -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-sm-3">
  <label for="NumeroDaOcorrencia" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.3</strong> Número da ocorrência
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="NumeroDaOcorrencia" maxlength="1000" placeholder="N° da ocorrência"
         asp-for="InqueritoModel.NumeroDaOcorrencia"
         type="text">
</div>

<!-- verifica input -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-sm-3">
  <label for="DataDaInstauracao" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.9</strong> Data da instauração
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="DataDaInstauracao" min="1900-01-01"
         asp-for="InqueritoModel.DataDaInstauracao"
         type="date">  
</div>
```

My attempt:

```js
function progressBarInq() {
            let progressBar0 = document.getElementById("InqProgress0");
            let progressBar25 = document.getElementById("InqProgress25");
            let progressBar50 = document.getElementById("InqProgress50");
            let progressBar75 = document.getElementById("InqProgress75");
            let progressBar100 = document.getElementById("InqProgress100");

            //25%
            let verInq1 = document.getElementById("InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial");            
            //50%
            let verInq5 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoIP");            
            //75%
            let verInq8 = document.getElementById("DataDoRelatorio");                          
            //100%
            let verInq11 = document.getElementById("NumeroDoProcesso");                        

            if (verInq1.value && verInq5.value && verInq8.value && verInq11.value) {
                progressBar0.style.display = "none";
                progressBar25.style.display = "block";
                progressBar50.style.display = "none";
                progressBar75.style.display = "none";
                progressBar100.style.display = "none";
            } 

progressBarInq();
```

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('DataDaInstauracao').value !== '')` You can put checks like this for all

Comment: Show your attempt. SO is not a free coding service; you are expected to do your best to try and solve your problem by yourself. When stuck, google for help; read what you find and try to incorporate it. If all fails, come back here with an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why not just add `required` to all of the inputs that must have a value?

Comment: @muasif80 Thank You!

Comment: @connexo Add attempt

Comment: @muasif80 rather than comparing strings, refer to using `length`, e.g. `(element.value.length != 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
verifyonClick = () => {
var first = document.getElementById("InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial")
var second = document.getElementById("NumeroDaOcorrencia")
var third = document.getElementById("DataDaInstauracao")
if(first.value && second.value && third.value)
alert("Value exist in every input")
else
alert("Please enter value in all fields")
}
```

```html
<!-- verifica select -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-md-4">
  <label for="InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.1</strong> Circunscrição policial
  </label>
  <select asp-for="InqueritoModel.COD_INQUERITO_CIRCUNSCRICAO_POLICIAL "
          asp-items="Model.ListCircunscricao"
          id="InqueritoCircunscricaoPolicial"
          class="select-codigo"
          onchange="mostrarOutroDeCombo(this, 'DSC_OUTRO_INQUERITO_CIRCUNSCRICAO_POLICIAL')">
    <option value="">Selecione a circunscrição</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- verifica input -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-sm-3">
  <label for="NumeroDaOcorrencia" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.3</strong> Número da ocorrência
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="NumeroDaOcorrencia" maxlength="1000" placeholder="N° da ocorrência"
         asp-for="InqueritoModel.NumeroDaOcorrencia"
         type="text">
</div>

<!-- verifica input -->

<div class="form-group pmd-textfield col-sm-3">
  <label for="DataDaInstauracao" class="control-label cssPerguntas espacamentoLabels">
    <strong>1.9</strong> Data da instauração
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="DataDaInstauracao" min="1900-01-01"
         asp-for="InqueritoModel.DataDaInstauracao"
         type="date">  
</div>

<div>
<button onclick="verifyonClick()"> submit </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for example!